# crontab - scheduling a job to run 6 min on hr and then every 15 mins

Tags: cron

I am trying to schedule a job which starts 6 mins past the hr every hr and then runs every 15 mins. So it kicks off at 10:06 then 10:21, 10:36,10:51. I know one way is :
06,21,36,51 * * * * /bin/foo

However why doesn't something like this work:
06/15 * * * *

Comment: Because no one found it useful enough to write the code and make sure it is unambiguous. Because that's the problem with this: You can try to add all kind of fancy syntaxes for adding times, but they must be easy to understand and precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want it separeted by comma with no space between it, so it takes place in all the minutes you want:

```
6,21,36,51 * * * * /bin/foo
```

or you could use it every 15 minutes which would look like this:

```
6-59/15 * * * * /bin/foo
```

For more information you can `man crontab 5` or check this url http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

**The 6/15 doesnt work because it doesnt know how to divide it, if you had it like 0-59/15 it could work but then it would not count the initial 6 that you wish for.**

The initial number should be a range that will be divided by the number after the `/` to run every X minutes (where X is the number that comes after the `/`) within the range you gave it.

another example would be 0-40/5 which would run every 5 minutes until the 40 minutes.

Comment: Would 6-59/15 have the right effect, do you think?

Comment: Yes i belive it would i won't say for certain as i dont make much use of irregular minutes like you want to but in theory yes it should work.